# Error in loop. ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Tags: mysql, odbc, pyodbc

I have an issue with a loop. I have a loop as follows:

```
for i in theList:

    temp=process_query('SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN=?', i)
    known_hours=process_query('SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?',(i))
```

where `theList` is defined as:

```
theList=process_query('SELECT DISTINCT SSN FROM Employee', None)
```

This now works without error, finally thanks to beargle. However I have found another issue that I cannot fix, namely that when I call the process_query function below:

```
def process_query(query, parameters):    
    if(parameters is None):    
        cursor1.execute(query)
    else:
        cursor1.execute(query, parameters)    (*LINE 33)

    n=0
    lista = []

    while 1:
        row = cursor1.fetchone()    
        if not row:
            break
        lista.append(row[0])
        n = n+1
    return lista
```

The trouble now is that the program complains at the second cursor1.execute (marked with a asterix, *) that ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000') which I believe stems from that `i` is a social security number and thus is not a single digit integer, but I cannot understand how to fix this issue.

edit: Here comes the whole loop with the whole print:

the loop (and some definitions)

```
theList=process_query('SELECT DISTINCT SSN FROM Employee', None)    
temp=[]

for i in theList:
    temp=process_query('SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?', (i))   (LINE 71)    
    known_hours=process_query('SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?',(i))    
    temp.append(known_hours)    
    unknown_hours=process_query('SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?', (i))    
    unknown_hours=map(int,unknown_hours)    
    temp.append(unknown_hours)    
    if(unknown_hours > 0):    
        temp.append('Yes')    
    else:    
        temp.append('No')    
    theList.append(temp)        
print theList
```

which gives the following print (NOTE! Ive also updated process_query so it prints out query and parameters (in that order).

```
SELECT DISTINCT SSN FROM Employee

None
SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

123456789

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?

123456789

SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?

123456789

SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

333445555

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?

333445555

SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?

333445555

SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

453453453

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?

453453453

SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?

453453453

SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

666884444

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?

666884444

SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?

666884444

SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

888665555

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?

888665555

SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?

888665555

SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

987654321

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?

987654321

SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?

987654321

SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

987987987

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?

987987987

SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?

987987987

SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

999887777

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Coalesce(Hours,0)) FROM Works_On WHERE ESSN=?

999887777

SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN=?

999887777

SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?

['John', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sumrpt2.py", line 72, in <module>
    temp=process_query('SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?', (i))
  File "sumrpt2.py", line 35, in process_query
    cursor1.execute(query, parameters)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Anyone have a clue?

Regards,
Cenderze

Comment: What is the (*) in the process_query function? Please add `print query, parameters` to the first line of the `process_query` function and update your question with the **full** output.

Comment: @beargle Thank you very much for replying! I've added those prints now and also the full output. The asterix in process_query is merely where the compiler complains of an error, which is more clear in the edit I did precisely now.

Comment: `theList` should only contain SSNs, but `
['John', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']` is somehow getting added. Make sure your data source only returns valid SSNs.

Comment: The `n=0 ... return lista` section of the `process_query` function can be replaced with `return cursor1.fetchall()`. You don't need to manually build the list when [cursor.fetchall()](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#fetchall) does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that parameters is expecting a list and is iterating over the number.

Try:

```
temp=process_query('SELECT FName, LName FROM Employee WHERE SSN= ?', [i])
```

To pass a list.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This clears up my previous errors but instead gives me: 'Python type list not supported.  param=1', 'HY097'
which I cannot quite understand from googeling it. Have you gotten it before or know how to handle those errors?

Comment: @GustavDanell Trying using `(i)` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for replying! This removes my earlier error but gives the original error: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Strange I think. Do you have any idea what it could be then?

Comment: @GustavDanell What do you get if you print out i?

Comment: If I print the temporary list, temp, at the end of the loop I get:

['John', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']

['Franklin', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']

['Joyce', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']

['Ramesh', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']

['James', [Decimal('0.0')], [1], 'Yes']

['Jennifer', [Decimal('35.0')], [0], 'Yes']

['Ahmad', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']

['Alicia', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']


(I have omitted some queries from my question)


and when I use:

 theList.append(temp)

inside the loop I get no output less all the errors if I print theList outside the loop.

Comment: Oh, and if I print "i" it is their social security number, which it is intended to be and if I print theList outside the loop the first line (With John etc.) is printed.

Comment: @GustavDanell It looks like it is the "known_hours" query that is causing the issue. Can you edit the question to show the full line?

Comment: Oh, did it not come with? I've edited it now. 

Do you want me to edit the whole loop? I merely thought it was some synthax error earlier so I omitted some code so it would be easier to see.

Comment: @GustavDanell I'm at a loss in that case. The only thing that could cause this that I could see would be if `i` was something like `['John', [Decimal('40.0')], [0], 'Yes']`. Hopefully someone else can help!

Comment: Yeah it is really strange to me as well. Thanks for your good efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to beargle's comment I could finally figure out what the problem was!

I know it is somewhat difficult to google these answers if you are in trouble yourself so I thought I could make a short summary of why this error arised:

In comments in these post several different approaches has been given to call the function which should work I believe.

However, as I did loop over 'i' in theList and I actually appended to it in my loop I got the error "'The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'".

Which I guess stems from the fact that in my queries I want merely one SSN but since I appended to theList it loops over different columns as well given me more markers than required (hence 4 parameters supplied where only 1 parameter marker is required).

Hope this helps someone who am as stuck as I was.

Thanks again beargle and everyone else who took time to help me!

Regards,